# Why is Minecraft lagging?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I bought a new Graphics card and power supply for my computer so that I could run games better. I got it and it works great- I can play games like Skyrim on full graphics with absolutely no lag. However, when I went back to play Minecraft on full-screen with upped settings, it still lags! Why is this, because my computer should be able to run no problem?

My graphics card is a [SAPPHIRE HD 7770 GHz Edition 1GB GDDR5](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?cid=1&gid=3&sgid=1159&pid=1452&&lid=1)

Comment: Minecraft can be CPU bound, and given your GPU, it probably is.  What processor are you running?

Comment: Are you running vanilla Minecraft, or are you running with mods?

Comment: Processor: AMD Athlon II X4 635.
Running pure vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should ensure you are running the appropriate Java version.  If you are a 64 bit machine then make sure you have the latest 64 bit version.  If you are 32 bit then get the latest 32 bit version.

That being said, it's quite possible that you need to allocate Java more memory.  Vanilla minecraft should run no problem on the default 1 GB of memory but if you install mods, that quickly becomes too little.  If you're on Linux (and probably works on Mac OS too) then simply put the flag '-Xmx2G' into the java command you start minecraft with.  This particular flag puts 2 Gigabytes (hence the 2G), if you wanted 3 Gigabytes you would use '-Xmx3G'.  If you are on windows, then [this](http://empireminecraft.com/threads/guide-how-to-allocate-more-memory-for-java-windows-mac.20011/) guide should help you.  If you are running vanilla minecraft and still get low FPS after giving it more memory it would be helpful for you to post your system specs (CPU, memory speed, memory amount, etc) as well as anything else you've tried already.

Comment: I accidentally came across the answer myself, and now that I know what it is, it fits in perfectly with what you were saying.

It

Comment: Mojang says Minecraft requires 2GB of memory (https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out if Minecraft is lagging or the whole machine is lagging. I had an instance where Minecraft was running slow on a friends computer and everything else was perfectly responsive. Increasing the memory allocation will fix this type of lag.

That said, please try willl459's answer first. If that doesn't not get you up to speed, you may need to look at disk I/O. basically, how fast your computer can read and write to the hard drive. Larger worlds in minecraft can take up a lot of HD space as well as take longer to load it from disk as you move around. You may need to think about upgrading to SSDs. I have seen and heard many successful minecraft speed ups from adding SSDs. They can be a bit pricey, though.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally came across the answer myself, and now that I know what it is, it fits in perfectly with what everyone was saying.

It's pretty simple: I had my Minecraft (Java) server up and running while I tried playing Minecraft, and I again noticed the lag (I already knew that having the server up made some games run slow, such as Skyrim). I turned it off and whadya know! The lag disappeared! Now the reason I posted this question in the first place was because when I originally experienced the lag, I remember going and checking to make sure the server was off... and I thought it was. Anyway, I either made a mistake and thought the server was off when it wasn't, or whatever the problem was fixed itself.

Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score -1):

You can also try a program called Razer Game Booster. I was getting between 12-20 FPS, then installed this program, added Minecraft to the game list. When i played the game, i checked the FOS and was over consistently over 60 FPS.

Also, the following site has a lot of useful information, including the Game Booster link.

http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-reduce-lag/